# What is a react js the way to learn?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I was a Java developer for coding Android for 3 years
But now I find that learning to React.Js brings me one step closer to world-class technology.
I did a lot of research on its learning path .
I realized that for React.js and React Native I had to learn the following sequence :

1-html
2-css
3-java script
4-react
5-react native

And learning node.js also helps me a lot in writing backend programs .

Because I had to work with html and CSS before. I remember this at the elementary and intermediate level.

My long-term goal is to design a site and software like the alibaba.ir

At the beginning of my learning, I was lost to a huge amount of framework and technologies . such as bootstrap and ...

Thank you for giving me your experience and introducing me to the right path that includes the best frameworks and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used React for 3 years. This is my [study blog](https://github.com/MuYunyun/blog) about React and some other knowledge.

`HTML + CSS + JavaScript` is very very important for everyone who want to be a FE engineer. And if you are familiar with JavaScript, React is easy to learn and use. The best way to learn React is to read the [official document](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

However it's only a start, there is too much possibility using React. You can research in every other hands as follow:

- How to manage store: Flux、Redux、Mobx、GraghQL...
- How to use css: Sass/less, css modules, Jss...
- How to fetch data: fetch、relay...
- How to use router?

Every direction has its own experts. Best wish to you.